# Move Logo inside Div

Tags: magento-2.1, layout, xml

i want to move the Logo inside a new Div Container with my custom default.xml.
But how can i do this? My default.xml look like this:

```
<referenceContainer name="header.container">
        <referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
            <container name="logo-wrapper" label="Page logo" as="logo-wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="logo content">
                <referenceBlock name="logo">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">148</argument>
                        <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">43</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </referenceBlock>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
</referenceContainer>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with the `move` command in your `default.xml`. You can read more about it here:

[Move blocks to other container how to](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109703/move-blocks-to-other-container-how-to)

and there is a good post about how to find out the name of the block that you need to move here:

[Find out the "name" for a referenceBlock in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102260/find-out-the-name-for-a-referenceblock-in-magento-2/162257#162257)