# What's the best way to find the correct referenceContainer?

Tags: magento2.3, custom

**SCENARIO**:

- I'm trying to hide the quantity field of my products frontend.
- So I go to 'app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml'
- And I try to hide it with:

  ```
  <referenceContainer name="product.add.form">
     <referenceBlock name="field.qty" remove="true"/>
  </referenceContainer>
  ```

And it doesn't do anything. So I'm trying to figure out what's the right combination of referenceContainer/Block to hide it.

**MY QUESTION IS:** What's the correct way to search for the container I want to hide? There's some way to figure out what's the correct one? Than you.

**EDIT:** I've found [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/198119/84480) but it doesn't seem to work with PHP 7.2.24 and/or magento 2.3.3.

Answer (score 0):

1) For removing a Block (using remove="true") you do not need to mention the exact referenceContainer name. just write the  code inside   **referenceContainer name="content"**

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
   <referenceBlock name="field.qty" remove="true"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

2) To find out what are the referenceContainer available , you may try to create a CMS widget from admin panel.

In widget creation page you will get the list of referenceContainer to select from under "**Layout Updates**" tab.
In that way you may sure what referenceContainer are available in your theme.